# Should I use sqlite3 for storing username and password with python?

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, sqlite

I am trying to build a simple login / register system with python sockets and Tkinter.

It might sound like a stupid question, but I really couldn't find by searching in Google.

I am wondering if using sqlite3 for storing username and password (with a server) is a good idea. If No, please explain why shouldn't I use sqlite3 and what is the alternative for this need.

Comment: Why do you think that you need a database for this?

Comment: Maybe you understand me incorrectly, Every user should type a username and password, the server saves the data, and stores it into a database.
When the client try to login again, the server know that he already regesters to the server... Am I right?

Comment: Ah, I see, you're using SQLite on the server. Yeah, don't do that.

Comment: So what is the alternative for not using sqlite3? what sould I use?

Comment: One that supports concurrency.

Comment: Can you give some examples for what should I use? thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Do not store passwords in plain text.  Store passwords in "salted hashes".  You can Google search for this, but here is a link to get you started: http://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to store the names and (secured) passwords on the server.  SQLite is a perfectly good solution for this but there are many, many other ways to do it.  If your application does not otherwise use a database for storage there's no need to add database support just for this simple task.  Assuming that you don't have a very large and every-growing list of users it could be as easy as pickling Python dictionary.

Comment: And where should I save the dictionary? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: PICKLING means use the Python pickle module to save arbitrary Python objects to a file.  If all your users/passwords fit easily in memory (which is usually true for non-public-facing systems) just keep the dictionary in memory and, whenever you add, remove, or update a user just pickle it to a disk file for backup (and read the pickled file when you start the server).

Comment: And please read about salting and hashing passwords -- never keep a plaintext password in your application or application's data.